# Error: cannot access an invalid/free'd bitmap here

Tags: android

1. On fragment onPause, I create a bitmap:

```
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(720, 1280, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

2. then call textureView's getBitmap

```
getBitmap(mBitmap);
```

3. then throw a fatal exception:

```
F Bitmap : Error, cannot access an invalid/free'd bitmap here!
```

Stack tree:

```
1 #00 pc 000442b8 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12) [armeabi-v7a::a699cc0495fb27c5d02d2f07457c9ac7]
2 #01 pc 00041eb9 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32) [armeabi-v7a::a699cc0495fb27c5d02d2f07457c9ac7]
3 #02 pc 0001b9d3 /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10) [armeabi-v7a::a699cc0495fb27c5d02d2f07457c9ac7]
4 #03 pc 00018c41 /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34) [armeabi-v7a::a699cc0495fb27c5d02d2f07457c9ac7]
5 #04 pc 00016804 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4) [armeabi-v7a::a699cc0495fb27c5d02d2f07457c9ac7]
6 #05 pc 0000929b /system/lib/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+86) [armeabi-v7a::732544599c30f6e6b85e83c6134e640a]
7 #06 pc 0008097f /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZNK7android6Bitmap11assertValidEv+18) [armeabi-v7a::cd82687a3f7f93e951d12444e0ef22cd]
8 java:
9 android.view.ThreadedRenderer.copyLayerInto(ThreadedRenderer.java:409)
10 android.view.HardwareLayer.copyInto(HardwareLayer.java:94)
11 android.view.TextureView.getBitmap(TextureView.java:590)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough score for commenting so posting as answer, Please post complete code of your fragment, also why are you creating it in OnPause but not in onCreate?and What is TextureView here? Your code may have following problems:

1- You have created a bitmap and not set it to any imageview thus this bitmap is not attached with imageview.

2-getBitmap method is supposed to return a bitmap you are passing same bitmap as argument.